# Concurrent access to static TableAdapter

Tags: c#, sql-server, multithreading

I have an asynchronous server which receives request from applications for data, the server spawns a thread for each request which trundles off and does the logic and sends a reply to the application when it is finished.

The data logic comes from a different version of the software which intended to be run on a local machine. Requests are handled on the clients side and data streamed from an SQL server. For this reason, all of the table adapters that are used are static, which works in this situation but causes some problems for my application.

The application requests data but the actual table adapter logic is done on the server, so we have multiple threads accessing the same table adapter and throwing exceptions about the place.

I'm at a loss, i've tried instantiating a new adapter for each unique thread request but it causes a "Command already being used by open table adapter". I've also tried spawning a new AppDomain for the functions accessing the static adapter but they end up doing nothing/crashing (not really sure as i can't seem to track them).

In short, trying to access a static table adapter across multiple threads. Any suggestions would be helpful but rewriting the data logic isn't really doable. I'm happy to provide code for different segments on request but at the moment it just seems to be a theory thing.

Comment: What kind of Server?  WCF has a ConcurrencyMode.

Comment: It's an asynchronous TCP based server using my own bit packet structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there's only one adapter then only one thread can use it at a time.  As such, you'd need to synchronise access to it such that only one thread does access it at a time.  You could wrap access to the adapter in a method that includes a 'lock' statement, thus blocking any subsequent threads until the current thread has finished.

Comment: Then it is as i feared. I was hoping to avoid this as there are several thousand adapters but i agree that this would work.

Comment: Not the answer i'm looking for :P but the right answer. Looking into using ThreadLocal for the adapters at the moment but if that fails i'll most likely have to rewrite the data logic to use locking.